# strcpy segfault copying file content to array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strcpy

This is my code

```
char url[MAX_WORD + 1];
char *urls[MAX_WORD + 1];
//char word[MAX_WORD + 1];

while(fscanf(fp, "%100s", url) == 1) {
    strcpy(urls[index], url);
    index++;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting on valgrind:

```
==43177== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==43177==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4844000
==43177==    at 0x4838DC8: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:512)
==43177==    by 0x109898: generateInvertedIndex (invertedIndex.c:102)
==43177==    by 0x1092B4: test1 (testInvertedIndex.c:36)
==43177==    by 0x109244: main (testInvertedIndex.c:23)
```

This is the content of the file it is copying from

```
nasa.txt
news1.txt
file11.txt
mixed.txt
planets.txt
file21.txt
info31.txt
```

I don't know how I am getting this error. I just want to copy the content of the file to an array of Urls. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your `urls` pointers do not point anywhere. You didn't initialize them.

Comment: `char *urls[MAX_WORD + 1];` is an array of `MAX_WORD + 1` **pointers** ; nothing more. Until you put some valid, writable addresses in that thing, their values are not viable targets for dereference, and that includes targeting from something like `strcpy`.

Comment: `strcpy(urls[index], url)` -> `urls[index] = strdup(url)`. [`Documentation for strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup). If `strdup` is not available on your platform you can write your own (2-3 lines of code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of uninitialized pointers or null pointers if the array is declared in the file scope

```
char *urls[MAX_WORD + 1];
```

So this call

```
strcpy(urls[index], url);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

It seems what you need is to declare a two-dimensional array like for example

```
char urls[MAX_WORD + 1][MAX_WORD + 1];
```

Or in the original array allocate dynamically memory for the stored string. Something like

```
urls[index] = malloc( strlen( url ) + 1 );
if ( urls[index] != NULL ) strcpy(urls[index], url);
else /* some error processing */;
```

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Not my downvote, but endless FAQ should be closed as duplicates, not answered for the purpose of grinding rep.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Not my DV., but maybe it was dvted because of the suggestion to have a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well, a 2D array seems like a very natural solution for a sequence of strings.-- At second thought it may have been downvoted for answering an obvious dup.